# async await in switch case statement does not work

Tags: javascript, angular

can we wait for the resolution of a promise within switch case statement, using the keyword await? in my angular component I have the following code which crashes my application.

```
switch (this.status) {
                case 'opened':
                  break;
                case 'payed':
                  this.getIntervalStatusSubscription.unsubscribe();
                  this.localStorageService.storePaymentIsMade(true);
                  await this.dbService.addOrderPaymentResult(ProcessResult.done, this.printerVMService.getSessionId()).toPromise();
                  this.router.navigate(['welcome/paying/paying_accepted']);
                  break;
                case 'closed':
                  this.getIntervalStatusSubscription.unsubscribe();
                  this.paymentSessionIsClosed = true;
                 await this.dbService.addOrderPaymentResult(ProcessResult.error, this.printerVMService.getSessionId()).toPromise();
                  this.router.navigate(['welcome']);
                  break;
                case 'used':
                  this.getIntervalStatusSubscription.unsubscribe();
                  this.router.navigate(['welcome']);
                  break;
                default:
                  console.error('status don\'t exist');
                  this.utils.displayAlertError(this.device.getIntervalStatus);
                  this.router.navigate(['welcome']);
              }
```

After several tests, the error seems to me to come from lines starting with `await`.
Can you tell me what's wrong please. I would like `this.dbService.addOrderPaymentResult(ProcessResult.done, this.printerVMService.getSessionId())` which returns an observable is executed synchronously before going to
`this.router.navigate(['welcome/paying/paying_accepted']);` that's why i chose to use `toPromise()` and `await`

Comment: Is Your swicth block inside an async function?

Comment: What error are you getting

Comment: Would it work if you fixed your indentation problem after `case 'closed'` ?

Comment: yes my swicth block is inside an async function

Comment: unfortunately the application being in production and only usable from a phone I could not see the error received

Comment: I tried again and it still works. thanks you for your help

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```js
async function trySwitch(status) {
    switch(status) {
        case 'opened':
            console.log('1');
            break;
        case 'closed':
            console.log('2');
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
            console.log('3');
            break;
    }
}

trySwitch('opened');
trySwitch('closed');
```

Comment: yes you are right it works very well. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: In my case I had to call the function, in this case trySwitch, with await. `await trySwitch('opened');`

Comment: Mind you that anything outside of the switch will run asynchronously. If you add `console.log('end')` after `trySwitch('closed')`, the output will be `1, 2, end, 3`.

Comment: @RodrigoPinto that's a fact about calling async functions in general. If you don't `await` the async function call, or `.then` it like a promise, the following code will run immediately. That's not unique to `switch` async logic